# How can I put an activity indicator on my view until chat is loading?

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to put a loader so that user can know that chat is being loaded when he first time enter the chat box.

Comment: you have to add the indicator programatically and add that indicator view to collection view. when chat loaded disappear that indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global activity indicator in the view controller namely "userDefinedActivityIndicator"

### Inside viewDidLoad() :

```
   self.userDefinedActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    self.userDefinedActivityIndicator?.startAnimating()
    self.userDefinedActivityIndicator?.isHidden = false
    self.userDefinedActivityIndicator?.center = self.view.center
```

After receiving proper response,stop animating the activity Indicator and hide it then show the results.